# Attempting to merge Record.js and driveApi

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have this record.js script to toggle a recording that is currently working as expected.

```
function Record_Current(config) {

    config = config || {};

    var self = this;
    var audioInput;
    var audioNode;
    var bufferSize = config.bufferSize || 4096;
    var recordedData = [];
    var recording = false;
    var recordingLength = 0;
    var startDate;
    var audioCtx;

    this.toggleRecording = function() {
        if (recording) {
            self.stop();
        } else {
            self.start();
        }
    };

    this.start = function() {

        // reset any previous data
        recordedData = [];
        recordingLength = 0;

        // webkit audio context shim
        audioCtx = new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

        if (audioCtx.createJavaScriptNode) {
            audioNode = audioCtx.createJavaScriptNode(bufferSize, 1, 1);
        } else if (audioCtx.createScriptProcessor) {
            audioNode = audioCtx.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);
        } else {
            throw 'WebAudio not supported!';
        }

        audioNode.connect(audioCtx.destination);

        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
            .then(onMicrophoneCaptured)
            .catch(onMicrophoneError);
    };
    this.stop = function() {
        stopRecording(function(blob) {
            self.blob = blob;
            config.onRecordingStop && config.onRecordingStop(blob);
        });
    };

    this.upload = function(url, params, callback) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("audio", self.blob, config.filename || 'recording.wav');

        for (var i in params)
            formData.append(i, params[i]);

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
            callback('progress', e, request);
        });
        request.upload.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
            callback('load', e, request);
        });

        request.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
            var status = 'loading';
            if (request.readyState === 4) {
                status = request.status === 200 ? 'done' : 'error';
            }
            callback(status, e, request);
        };

        request.open("POST", url);
        request.send(formData);
    };


    function stopRecording(callback) {
        // stop recording
        recording = false;

        // to make sure onaudioprocess stops firing
        window.localStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => { track.stop(); });
        audioInput.disconnect();
        audioNode.disconnect();

        exportWav({
            sampleRate: sampleRate,
            recordingLength: recordingLength,
            data: recordedData
        }, function(buffer, view) {
            self.blob = new Blob([view], { type: 'audio/wav' });
            callback && callback(self.blob);
        });
    }

    function onMicrophoneCaptured(microphone) {

        if (config.visualizer)
            visualize(microphone);

        // save the stream so we can disconnect it when we're done
        window.localStream = microphone;

        audioInput = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(microphone);
        audioInput.connect(audioNode);

        audioNode.onaudioprocess = onAudioProcess;

        recording = true;
        self.startDate = new Date();

        config.onRecordingStart && config.onRecordingStart();
        sampleRate = audioCtx.sampleRate;
    }

    function onMicrophoneError(e) {
        console.log(e);
        alert('Unable to access the microphone.');
    }

    function onAudioProcess(e) {
        if (!recording) {
            return;
        }

        recordedData.push(new Float32Array(e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0)));
        recordingLength += bufferSize;

        self.recordingLength = recordingLength;
        self.duration = new Date().getTime() - self.startDate.getTime();

        config.onRecording && config.onRecording(self.duration);
    }

    function visualize(stream) {
        var canvas = config.visualizer.element;
        if (!canvas)
            return;

        var canvasCtx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

        var analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
        analyser.fftSize = 2048;
        var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
        var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

        source.connect(analyser);

        function draw() {
            // get the canvas dimensions
            var width = canvas.width,
                height = canvas.height;

            // ask the browser to schedule a redraw before the next repaint
            requestAnimationFrame(draw);

            // clear the canvas
            canvasCtx.fillStyle = config.visualizer.backcolor || '#fff';
            canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

            if (!recording)
                return;

            canvasCtx.lineWidth = config.visualizer.linewidth || 2;
            canvasCtx.strokeStyle = config.visualizer.forecolor || '#f00';

            canvasCtx.beginPath();

            var sliceWidth = width * 1.0 / bufferLength;
            var x = 0;


            analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);

            for (var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {

                var v = dataArray[i] / 128.0;
                var y = v * height / 2;

                i === 0 ? canvasCtx.moveTo(x, y) : canvasCtx.lineTo(x, y);
                x += sliceWidth;
            }

            canvasCtx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height / 2);
            canvasCtx.stroke();
        }

        draw();
    }

    function exportWav(config, callback) {
        function inlineWebWorker(config, cb) {

            var data = config.data.slice(0);
            var sampleRate = config.sampleRate;
            data = joinBuffers(data, config.recordingLength);

            console.log(data);

            function joinBuffers(channelBuffer, count) {
                var result = new Float64Array(count);
                var offset = 0;
                var lng = channelBuffer.length;

                for (var i = 0; i < lng; i++) {
                    var buffer = channelBuffer[i];
                    result.set(buffer, offset);
                    offset += buffer.length;
                }

                return result;
            }

            function writeUTFBytes(view, offset, string) {
                var lng = string.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < lng; i++) {
                    view.setUint8(offset + i, string.charCodeAt(i));
                }
            }

            var dataLength = data.length;

            // create wav file
            var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44 + dataLength * 2);
            var view = new DataView(buffer);

            writeUTFBytes(view, 0, 'RIFF'); // RIFF chunk descriptor/identifier
            view.setUint32(4, 44 + dataLength * 2, true); // RIFF chunk length
            writeUTFBytes(view, 8, 'WAVE'); // RIFF type
            writeUTFBytes(view, 12, 'fmt '); // format chunk identifier, FMT sub-chunk
            view.setUint32(16, 16, true); // format chunk length
            view.setUint16(20, 1, true); // sample format (raw)
            view.setUint16(22, 1, true); // mono (1 channel)
            view.setUint32(24, sampleRate, true); // sample rate
            view.setUint32(28, sampleRate * 2, true); // byte rate (sample rate * block align)
            view.setUint16(32, 2, true); // block align (channel count * bytes per sample)
            view.setUint16(34, 16, true); // bits per sample
            writeUTFBytes(view, 36, 'data'); // data sub-chunk identifier
            view.setUint32(40, dataLength * 2, true); // data chunk length

            // write the PCM samples
            var index = 44;
            for (var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
                view.setInt16(index, data[i] * 0x7FFF, true);
                index += 2;
            }

            if (cb) {
                return cb({
                    buffer: buffer,
                    view: view
                });
            }

            postMessage({
                buffer: buffer,
                view: view
            });
        }

        var webWorker = processInWebWorker(inlineWebWorker);

        webWorker.onmessage = function(event) {
            callback(event.data.buffer, event.data.view);

            // release memory
            URL.revokeObjectURL(webWorker.workerURL);
        };

        webWorker.postMessage(config);
    }

    function processInWebWorker(_function) {
        var workerURL = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([_function.toString(),
            ';this.onmessage = function (e) {' + _function.name + '(e.data);}'
        ], {
            type: 'application/javascript'
        }));

        var worker = new Worker(workerURL);
        worker.workerURL = workerURL;
        console.log(worker);
        return worker;
    }

    function renderRecording(workerURL, list) {
        const worker_url = URL.createObjectURL(workerURL);
        const li = document.createElement('li');
        const audio = document.createElement('audio');
        const anchor = document.createElement('a');
        anchor.setAttribute('href', workerURL);
        const now = new Date();
        anchor.setAttribute(
            'download',
            `recording-${now.getFullYear()}-${(now.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}-${now.getDay().toString().padStart(2, '0')}--${now.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0')}-${now.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0')}-${now.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0')}.webm`
        );
        anchor.innerText = 'Download';
        audio.setAttribute('src', worker_url);
        audio.setAttribute('controls', 'controls');
        li.appendChild(audio);
        li.appendChild(anchor);
        list.appendChild(li);
    }
}
```

and this Google Drive Script

```
var driveLink = require('stream');

module.exports.uploadFile = function(req) {
    var file;
    console.log("driveApi upload reached")

    function blobToFile(req) {
        file = req.body.blob
        file.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
        file.name = req.body.word;
        return file;
    }

    var bufStream = new stream.PassThrough(); 
    bufStream.end(file);

    console.log(typeof 42);
    var folderId = "Folder"; // Enter Folder Name
    var fileMetadata = {
        "name": req.body.word,
        parents: [folderId]
    }
    var media = {
        mimeType: "audio/mp3",
        body: bufStream
    }

    drive.files.create({
        auth: jwToken,
        resource: fileMetadata,
        media: media,
        fields: "id"
    }, function(err, file) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.log("File Id: ", file.id);
        }
        console.log("driveApi upload accomplished")
    });
}
```

I have tried a few different approaches to combining the two to make it so it automatically saves the .wav file to the Drive API but it does not work.

I believe I am either not merging the two scripts together the right way or I am missing something. Do I need to use V3 of the Google API?

If anyone could provide some guidance on how to merge the two properly that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!